# How to set an image which is already on the server as product image

Tags: image, media

Is there a way to select images from the servers media storage (exactly like when editing the content of a CMS page and hitting "insert image...") as product image?

Unfortunately we only found the flash uploader in the image tab when editing a product but no possibility to access the server images. And we need to associate a lot of images (all together nearly 10 GB) with a lot of products and cannot do it automatically as the file names are pretty much random, so it would be a real waste of time to download all images just to re-upload them again (especially as it looks like Magento already has the feature but only for CMS pages...).

Thanks for any tips on how this could be done.

Comment: How did you get the 10 GB of images in the first place?

Comment: Also off topic: the company involved in this project has no real online shop till now and sells a lot of products from a lot of different producers. To each product line they got the products together with images from the producers. They 'collected' or better horded these images over the last years and the producers often also weren't very observantly naming/tagging these images. Often there is only a folder i. e. "collection 2013" with a ton of pictures like "IMG_000.jpg". I guess you see where this is going...

Comment: Yeah I do. I was curious to see if the pulled them from a url. Seems like a difficult task to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the product import for updating or adding new products you could add the image location to it's associated products but if as you said the images are named randomly this could be pretty difficult. 
Other than that you will probably have to upload the images from whatever computer you are using.